# Why can't Travis CI create a directory during an npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

My most recent commit has somehow caused Travis CI to stop working when it tries to run `npm install`. My only change was a correcting a typo calling a  Javascript file (from `fooBar/foo-bar.js` to `foo-bar/foo-bar.js`), so I'm not sure if the commit itself was the cause. The error I receive from Travis CI is as follows:

```
bower                                               EACCES EACCES, mkdir '/public'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/public'
    at Error (native)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:83:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Logger.emit (/home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
    at /home/travis/build/myWorkplace/mySite/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
System info:
Bower version: 1.7.7
Node version: 0.12.2
OS: Linux 3.13.0-40-generic x64
```

Unfortunately, Travis CI was set up for us by a contractor, so I don't know what more information to provide, but if there's anything more that will help, I'll be happy to find it out.

EDIT:
Looking at a log for a successful run, it looks like the `mkdir` line is new to this build...

EDIT2:
Here are my `.travis.yml` and `bower.json`:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- 0.12.2
services:
- mongodb
before_install: npm install -g grunt-cli
install: npm install
before_script: grunt && grunt --target=admin
env:
  global:
  - NODE_ENV: test
  - PORT: 5000
  - SSL: "off"
  - TOKEN_SECRET: [xxx]
  - MONGO_URI: mongodb://localhost:27017/myWorkplace-test
  - BUCKET: myWorkplacebucket
  - AWS_REGION: us-west-2
  - CDN: https://[xxx].cloudfront.net
  - POSTMARK_API_KEY: POSTMARK_API_TEST
  - MAIL_FROM_NAME: myWorkplace
  - MAIL_FROM_EMAIL: user@myWorkplace.com
  - AIRBRAKE: [xxx]
  - secure: [xxx]
  - secure: [xxx]
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    access_key_id: [xxx]
    secret_access_key:
      secure: [xxx]
    bucket: "myWorkplace-builds"
    skip_cleanup: true
    region: us-west-2
    local_dir: dist
    on:
      branch: master
  - provider: s3
    access_key_id: [xxx]
    secret_access_key:
      secure: [xxx]
    bucket: "myWorkplace-builds-dev"
    skip_cleanup: true
    region: us-west-2
    local_dir: dist
    on:
      branch: dev
  - provider: codedeploy
    access_key_id: [xxx]
    secret_access_key:
      secure: [xxx]
    revision_type: github
    region: us-west-2
    application: mySite
    deployment_group: devs
    on:
      branch: dev
  - provider: codedeploy
    access_key_id: [xxx]
    secret_access_key:
      secure: [xxx]
    revision_type: github
    region: us-west-2
    application: mySite
    deployment_group: production
    on:
      branch: master
notifications:
  slack: myWorkplace:[xxx]
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "myWorkplace",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "authors": [
    "Foo User <user@myWorkplace.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.11",
    "jquery": "2.1.2",
    "angular-route": "1.3.11",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.11",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.11",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.11",
    "less": "2.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.1",
    "moment": "2.8.3",
    "html5-boilerplate": "4.3.0",
    "lodash": "3.1.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-show-errors": "2.0.0",
    "autofill-event": "1.0.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.11",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.0.0",
    "angular-file-upload": "1.1.5",
    "d3": "3.3.10",
    "iso-currency": "~0.2.1",
    "angular-moment": "0.8.2",
    "angular-filter": "0.5.1",
    "angular-busy": "~4.1.2",
    "angular-csv-import": "0.0.14",
    "angulartics": "0.17.2",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "1.0.0",
    "ng-idle": "1.0.0",
    "iso-4217-currency-codes-angular": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.3.11",
    "d3": "3.5.5"
  }
}
```

EDIT3: I reran a previous Travis build that previously succeeded, and it failed with the same error. This leads me to think some sort of update to a module has made it no longer work. I'm not sure though. Of note, perhaps, is some lines saying `graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.` I don't know how to update it though, since `graceful-fs` isn't in the `package.json` that gets committed to the repository...

Comment: Is it creating `/public` at the root of the container where you may not have permission ?

Comment: That's what it looks like. But why wouldn't Travis be able to write to its root? I and how would that permission have been _lost_? Or perhaps it's now trying to do that `mkdir` but before it wasn't?

Comment: Try a relative path: `mkdir public` instead of `mkdir /public` (remove the leading slash in the config that produce that side effect)

Comment: Looking at a log for a successful run, it looks like `mkdir` is indeed new to this build...

Comment: @topheman How do I change that? My `.travis.yml` doesn't have any reference to `mkdir` or `/public`.

Comment: Sorry can't help you about that without seeing at least the `.travis.yml` (and probably your build chain like gulp or any other build tool causing this side effect)

Comment: Hint: check your `bower.json` file, this is more likely to be there

Comment: I reran a previous Travis build that previously succeeded, and it failed with the same error. This leads me to think some sort of update to a module has made it no longer work. I'm not sure though. Of note, perhaps, is some lines saying `graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.`

Comment: Also, the line right before the error is `bower d3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the root cause of the issue was a package that was updated and no longer working in my environment. I fixed it by locking in all the versions in my `package.json` to versions that I know worked previously.